# Http message on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a total noob in node.js (and internet tech. in general). On my assignment from the uni. in which we were asked to develop an http server, I have been requested to do the following:

> Implementation details: upon receiving a message from the ‘client’ (socket, data and end events), assume it’s an HTTP message and parse it, if it’s not(an HTTP message) you should return an HTTP response(status 400).

My question is: How to parse the the message given, and how should I expect the message to look like?  Bottom line, how does an http message looks like?

Thank you!

Comment: [Time to read the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Comment: Node.js has its own HTTP library; do you need to parse the raw data yourself or are you supposed to use the library?

Comment: @pimvdb will be happy to know both ways, meaning using the library and parsing it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node itself uses a [http_parser](https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/deps/http_parser) written in C.

It's based on NGINX's HTTP parser with some extensions by the node core team.

Node's http module then [uses it](var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser;)

`var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser;`

For [example](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js#L1100) the `ClientRequest::onSocket` uses a parser.

```
ClientRequest.prototype.onSocket = function(socket) {
  var req = this;
  process.nextTick(function() {
    var parser = parsers.alloc();
    // [snip]
  });
};
```

If you actually want to write your own parser then have fun parsing the [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

If you don't know how to write a parser, then read up on [Parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: does this mean that for every type(socket,data,events) i should create such a parser?

Comment: No. you should extract the information from the socket's data and end events then run it through the parser.